# Why can I view images assets if the asset link is broken?

Tags: assets, image

I just uploaded my site to a live server.  My image assets all show a grayed-out broken image icon.  I assume this is because the image assets settings are not set to the correct new path.

If so, why can I view the image when I select it and the images appear on all pages and posts?

Comment: You mean the Asset thumbnails are broken?  Are they 404'ing in your browser's console?  500'ing? My guess would be your live site is using GD and staging/dev had Imagick and the images are in a format on production that GD doesn't recognize.

Comment: I noticed if I wait long enough in Safari most of the asset thumbnails  (>80%) appear.   In Chrome, it takes longer and only about half the images appears.   All images are jpg. And file size does not appear to be a factor.